# Resident set size increase for a simple loop in bash script

Tags: bash, memory-leaks

When I try a very simple script.
Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
        sleep 1
        echo "hello"
done
```

I realize that it continue increase RSS (Resident set size, check by ps command).

Is there anyone can help me explain why? and how to keep RSS constantly?

Comment: How long do you run the loop to get a significant increase in RSS?

Comment: around some minutes I re-check RSS by ps command, then I saw increase